# Como eliminar estes "callbacks" excessivos quando utilizado promises e subscribes no TS?

Tags: ionic, angular, typescript

Estou trabalhando com ionic 2 e preciso fazer uma requisição no storage para resgatar um token salvo anteriormente, após fazer essa requisição preciso enviar este token para a API para que seja validado. O problema é que estou poluindo o meu código com `Promise` e `subscribe` que está gerando essa cascata exemplificada abaixo:

```
public check(): Promise<boolean> {
    return new Promise(resolve => {
        this.storage.get('token').then((token) => {
            this.network.onConnect().subscribe(() => {
                if(this.network.type != 'none' && this.network.type != 'unknown') {
                    this.http.post('localhost/auth', {
                        token: token
                    }).map(response => response.json()).subscribe(data => {
                        resolve(data.status);
                    });
                }
            });
        });
    });
}

...

check().then(status => {
    if(!status)
        ...
});
```

Há alguma solução mais elegante para este caso?

Comment: Isso é AngularJS ou Angular2?

Comment: Estou utilizando o Angular 2